# Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail in reactjs

Tags: react-redux

I am trying to integrate react-redux-form with react-bootstrap.

this is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Control,Form,actions,Errors } from 'react-redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap';
class UserRegistration extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        const required = (val) => val && val.length;
        const ReduxFormControl = ({input, meta, ...props}) => {
            return <ReactBootstrap.FormControl {...props} {...input} />
        };

        const Forms = ({input, meta, ...props}) => {
            return <ReactBootstrap.Form {...props} {...input} />
        };
        return (
            <Form model="userReg" onSubmit={(userReg) => dispatch(actions.load("userReg",userReg))}  component={Forms} >
                <label >fname</label>
                <Control.text model="userReg.fname" validators={{required}} placeholder="Name" component={ReduxFormControl}  />
                <Errors model="userReg.fname" messages={{required:'required'}} />
                <label>lame</label>
            <Control.text model="userReg.lname" validators={{required}} placeholder="lame" component={ReduxFormControl}  />
                <button type="submit">register</button>              
            </Form >
        )
    }
}
export default connect (null)(UserRegistration);
```

when I pass the form component into the redux form tag it shows following error.

```
index.js:2178 Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail.

Check the render method of `Form`.
    in Forms (created by Form)
    in Form (created by Connect(Form))
    in Connect(Form) (at registration.js:18)
    in UserRegistration (created by Connect(UserRegistration))
    in Connect(UserRegistration) (created by Route)
    in Route (at routes.js:14)
    in div (at routes.js:10)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at routes.js:9)
    in routes (at index.js:13)
    in Provider (at index.js:12)
```

can someone help me to solve this warning and is there any other better way for integrating both react -bootstrap and react-redux-form?